# ServletFileUpload parseRequest() compilation error while uploading files with servlet and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to implement **images uploading** using servlet and JSP.

My JSP page is pretty simple and has only the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="Select an image..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Now" />
</form>
```

The corresponding servlet and servlet-mapping is described in `web.xml`.
And my `doPost` method looks as:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    FileItemFactory itemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemFactory);

    if (!contentType.equals("image/png")) {
        out.println("Only PNG image files supported.");
        continue;
    }

    try {
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request); // here is an error
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            String contentType = item.getContentType();

            File uploadDir = new File(UPLOAD_DIR);
            File file = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", uploadDir);

            item.write(file);

            out.println("File uploaded.");
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        out.println("Upload failed.");
        return;
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains on the following line: `List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);`:

> The method `parseRequest(RequestContext)` in the file FileUploadBase is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest).

While in the answer [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) this method doesn't produce any errors:

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see here [org.apache.commons.fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html)
The request should be ServletRequestContext not HttpServletRequest :

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve problem

```
DiskFileItemFactory diskFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
diskFactory.setSizeThreshold(4000);
diskFactory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(diskFactory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```